# How can I embed a camera view into an Android application using appcelerator?

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-alloy

I've added a square view on my window and I would like to be able to show camera image in the view.

```
var containerView = Ti.UI.createView({
    height: 150,
    width: 150,
    backgroundColor: "blue",
});
win.add(containerView)
```

How can I intergrate such code into the containerView? I don't want to take pictures, just want the camera open in the view with crosshair.

```
Ti.Media.showCamera({
    success: function(e){},
    error: function (e) {},
    cancel: function (e) {},
    allowEditing: false,
    showControls: true,
    saveToPhotoGallery: false,
    mediaTypes:[Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO],
    videoQuality: Ti.Media.QUALITY_HIGH,
    overlay: myOverlay /***Implement crosshair overlay***/
});
```

Comment: Looking at the docs, I don't think this is possible without creating a custom module.  You can do it the other way round though by adding containerView on top of the camera by setting "overlay: containerView" in the showCamera options.

Comment: forget that, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

iOS: This module will apparently allow you to display a camera feed as a view with a custom width/height http://gitt.io/component/be.k0suke.ticamera

Android: This module should do the same http://gitt.io/component/pw.custom.androidcamera

I haven't used either but looking at the github documentation it seems to do what you need.

There are a few other camera modules on gitt.io which might take your fancy too: http://gitt.io/search?q=camera

Comment: Thanks phil, this is exactly what I need but unfortunately, this module is only for iOS.  Do you know of any such library for Android?